# Parsing Custom node value through SimplePie

Tags: parsing, rss, simplepie

I am parsing yahoo media rss feeds through `SimplePie` library.
I had a need to add custom node named `<category>` as a child node to `<title>`.
Now I need to parse the content of that node every time through the loop...
Here is a structure of my feed

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <channel>
   .....
   .....
    <item>
      <title></title>
      <link></link>
      ....
      <media:content>
      ...
      </media:content>
      <category>one</category> 
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>...</title>
      <link>...</link>
      ....
      <media:content>
      ...
      </media:content>
      <category>two</category> 
    </item> 
  </channel>
</rss>
```

My task is to parse the content of the `<category>` nodes
I have tried using `$item->get_item_tags()` the following way, but no luck, I get `null` in return

```
$cat_get= $item->get_item_tags('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/',
            'item');
            $cat_get_node = $category1[0]['child']['http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/']['category'];
            $cat_content = $category2[0]['data'];
```

Any direction will be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, as the element is in the root namespace.

```
$cat = $item->get_item_tags(SIMPLEPIE_NAMESPACE_RSS20, 'category');
$cat_content = $cat[0]['child'];
```